# accessing to image in eclipse plugin

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I'm trying to set the background image of canvas using

```
canvas.setBackgroundImage(image);
```

How can i set the **image** with a ***.png file** that is stored in plugin's image sub-directory ?

Something like this:

```
PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getSharedImages().getImage(ISharedImages.IMG_OBJS_INFO_TSK)
```

but I want to use my image file instead of the shared image.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For images not declared in the plugin.xml, like in [this thread](https://web.archive.org/web/20090810212525/http://dev.eclipse.org/newslists/news.eclipse.platform.rcp/msg36814.html):

```
 public Image createImage(String path) {
   Image image = getImageRegistry().get(path);
   if (image == null) {
     getImageRegistry().put(path, AbstractUIPlugin.
       imageDescriptorFromPlugin(ID, path));
     image = getImageRegistry().get(path);
   }
   return image;
 }
```

(similar to "[FAQ How do I create an image registry for my plug-in?](http://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_create_an_image_registry_for_my_plug-in%3F)")

See also [User interface resources](http://help.eclipse.org/help33/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/guide/jface_resources.htm) for accessing resources declared within your plugin.

Comment: @treeno Thank you. I have restored that link.